# css style datepicker issue with flatly bootswatch theme

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the flaty bootstarp theme found [here](http://bootswatch.com/flatly/). and the datepicker component found [here](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/)

When in use, the date pciker appears like this

[image: date picker]

What styles do i change to make it look right, i dont want to mess with the css. Here is the issue is http://jsfiddle.net/hwPcF/4/

```
<input class="span2" id='dp3' size="16" type="text">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dp3').datepicker({
            format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
            autoclose: true
        });
});
```

Comment: You should upload your code to http://jsfiddle.net/ to help you out

Comment: You probably need to make css adjustments, but we can only help you if you show some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the below css to you file

```
body{
color: #ccc;
}
```

***EDIT:*** I got your problem,  **your are missing the css file for the datepicker**.

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/hwPcF/6/)

I think this is your expectation right?

[image]

**EDIT2:** I just checked the bootstrap datepicker and made a few change to look similar to it.

```
.datepicker{
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
}
```

Check [**JSFiddle2**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/hwPcF/10/) and now it looks like

[image]

> Some css file conflict is occurring, trying to figure out.

Comment: which file, and hope it wont affect other css styling, as its applied to the whole body

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to your css file

> .datepicker-days { color: #eee; }

will turn your day numbers gray.